# convert each character to different character python

Tags: python, python-2.7

> The first piece of software will take a text and convert each character ( letters, numbers, spaces) into a different character. For example "a" will be converted to "x"," b" will be converted to"k". The choice of which letter should convert each letter is up to you ( any substituation is fine , foe example, if you want "a" to be converted to "b"' that's fine too".

I want to help and not a solution

Comment: Look at `string.translate()`

Comment: Or at ASCII table and `chr()`/`ord()` functions

Comment: FWIW, you might want to check out the Python documentation to see what methods string supports: http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html

Comment: But can be reversed and retained or invoiced value of the original

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample.

Anything more comprehensive you will have to do on your own:

```
>>> import string
>>> table = string.maketrans('ab', 'xk')
>>> s = 'sample string with both characters'
>>> string.translate(s, table)
'sxmple string with koth chxrxcters'
```